# Executar controller de um site externo

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, controller

Tenho o seguinte problema/questão:

Tenho o `Wordpress` instalado e o `CodeIgniter` também. No CodeIgniter tenho que fazer uma função que adicionar **+1** no banco de dados quando uma categoria é vista no `wordpress`. Então o seguinte código dentro de um `controller` do `codeigniter`

```
<?php
function add($id){

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$banner = $this->db->get('banners')->row();
$add = $banner->views + 1;

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('banners', array('views'=>$add));

return true;
?>
```

Preciso executar esse código toda vez que alguém ir para uma categoria do `wordpress`. Pensei em fazer usando `file_get_contents()` mas não sei se vai funcionar porque ele pega o conteúdo de um link. Queria saber como posso fazer. O arquivo do `wordpress` relacionado a categorias eu já sei, o problema só está em fazer/usar uma função para executar quando entrar ou atualizar a página, pois quero fazer um sistema de visualização de banners.